# Closed because unicorns not working

Tags: bug

I bought the "Closed because unicorns" power, but it won't let me close any questions with it. The feature doesn't seem to be working as advertised.

I still have all of the standard "closed" options, and I don't appear to have any new options.

Answer (score 8):

The description says

> "Closed because unicorns" is the only **valid** close reason.

(emphasis mine). There are other reasons to choose from, but they're not valid, so the question will be closed because unicorns no matter what you choose.*

<sub>*technically, that excludes "belongs on" and "duplicate" closure.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

It only changes the reasons on question that are already closed to read they were closed because of unicorns.

[image]